# Plotly to pdf report

Tags: r, shiny, knitr, r-markdown, plotly

I'd like to add a plotly plot to a pdf file. This should be done locally (without plotly_IMAGE). Unfortunately I do not have access to webshot (since I do not have the rights to install PhantomJS). Therefore I tried a workaround described here: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/311 using shiny gadgets. But I wanted to adapt it such that the copying is doen without clicking done in the gadget.

All my attempts (see below) failed because I was not able to delay the downloadHandler until the copying was done.

Any suggestions how the dresired result (copy plotly-Image as png first and use it in pdf-Export afterwards) all done sequentially after click on Download Button?

ui:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(rsvg)


shinyUI(fluidPage(
  title = 'Download a PDF report',
  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      helpText(),
      selectInput('x', 'Build a regression model of mpg against:',
                  choices = names(mtcars)[-1]),
      radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'),
                   inline = TRUE),
      downloadButton('downloadReport'),
      tags$script('
       document.getElementById("downloadReport").onclick = function() {
          var plotly_svg = Plotly.Snapshot.toSVG(
            document.querySelectorAll(".plotly")[0]
      );

                  Shiny.onInputChange("plotly_svg", plotly_svg);
          };
       ')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput('regPlot')
    )
  )
))
```

server:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(rsvg)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$regPlot <- renderPlotly({
    library(plotly)
    set.seed(100)
    d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
    print("render")
    p <- plot_ly(d, x = carat, y = price, text = paste("Clarity: ", clarity),
            mode = "markers", color = carat, size = carat)
    p
  })

  observeEvent(input$plotly_svg, priority = 10, {
    png_gadget <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
    png_gadget <- "out.png"
    print(png_gadget)
    rsvg_png(charToRaw(input$plotly_svg), png_gadget)
  })

  output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('my-report', sep = '.', switch(
        input$format, PDF = 'pdf', HTML = 'html', Word = 'docx'
      ))
    },

    content = function(file) {
      src <- normalizePath('testreport.Rmd')

      # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
      # permission to the current working directory
      owd <- setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))
      file.copy(src, 'testreport.Rmd')

      library(rmarkdown)
      out <- render('testreport.Rmd', params = list(region = "Test"), switch(
        input$format,
        PDF = pdf_document(), HTML = html_document(), Word = word_document()
      ))
      file.rename(out, file)
    }
  )
})
```